# What does `e` modifer mean in preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match, pcre

I am reviewing PHP code right now for suspicious code. I have found

```
preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($var1, '/') . '/ie', $var2)
```

But php does not raise any warning like `The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in` or `Unknown modifier 'e' in`.

Test: http://3v4l.org/6i8ln

Does `e (PREG_REPLACE_EVAL)` modifier have special meaning for `preg_match` or just ignored?

Comment: The `e` modifier is deprecated. Don't use it for new code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in `preg_match()` the modifier e won't do anything and is also deprecated. You can read more about it in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

And two quotes from there:

> **Warning:**
>   This feature has been **DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.5.0**. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

> **Note:**
>   **Only preg_replace()** uses this modifier; it is **ignored** by **other PCRE functions**.